# Time off from work due to family breakdown

Tags: work-life-balance

My partner just received a call from her younger brother saying her parents are splitting and she needs to come home, she is 34 weeks pregnant and its a 3.5 hour drive to where her family lives and I don't want her making it alone as the road isn't the best.

So what would be the best way of asking my boss for a couple of days so I can take her home to help sort things out??

Comment: "she is 34 weeks pregnant and its a 3.5 hour drive to where her family lives" - I understand this is a pretty bad situation your wife needs to attend to, but make sure she checks with her doctor before she leaves. A lot of OBs don't like their patients going that far from home that late in the pregnancy. At the very least, make sure that she has a plan in the event something pregnancy-related (early labor, etc.) comes up.

Comment: Do you have vacations days/ personal days?

Comment: Isn't this based on the relationship you have with your boss and your status as an employee with your current company? Maybe her younger brother could take a bus and go along with her instead of you taking off of work. Not to be insensitive but a divorce between people who have working-age children is not exactly a life and death situation.

Comment: It's probably an "I wouldn't have started here" type answer, but... what will your partner's presence achieve?  It's very unlikely to prevent a split or make it less acrimonious, and her parents are adults who presumably can take care of their own affairs (particularly if this has been brewing for a while). Meanwhile, at 34 weeks your partner needs to look after herself and the baby, she doesn't need to be spending long hours in the car and walking headfirst  into distressing situations. Push back against the brother, not your boss!

Comment: I know that the men in a family often expect the women to handle any family emergencies, but I would tell the brother that she cannot travel right now and he has to handle it. Risking her life and her baby's life for something that she does not need to be the one to handle is just a bad idea. At this point in time, the baby's health and her health should come first.

Comment: To be honest, it's not really an emergency. The parents have probably lived together for many years, so if they can't stay another few weeks together until the baby has arrived then they need their heads banged together. So the first thing would be to call the parents, and tell them to get their act together and not separate at this very bad time. And if they think they need to split right now, then it's their job to look after their son.

Answer (score 12):

Tell your boss that you have a family emergency give your boss the details that you just gave us.

1. Tell your boss specifically how many days off you need. If you need three days and on the second day you are off, it turns out that you need two more, call him immediately and let him know of the changed situation.
2. As part of you telling the boss that you want the time off, state that you will spend the rest of the days tying up any loose ends that need to be tied and that you will brief your colleagues on any of your tasks that they can take over from you while you are gone. Tell your boss that anyone can call you at any time should they need clarifications or instructions from you. You'll call back when you get either to the destination or the nearest pit stop. Tell your boss that you will make sure before you leave that your affairs are in such order that you can pick up where you left off when you come back.

Be direct and to the point when you talk to the boss - every minute counts and you have to act like every minute counts.

Don't forget to update your voice mail and your company email with an "out of the office" message before you leave.

Comment: I will point out that you don't necessarily have to give details on a family emergency, but it does generally make it easier for the boss to say yes if he knows what is up. However, since these two are not married, he may find it diffult to get family emergency leave if he discusses why. When my partner was dying, the company had to change their policy so that they could give me bereavement leave. His company may have simliar restrictions in place as to what consititutes a family emergency.

Comment: @HLGEM Good point. I'd say, it's important to either build or keep the trust and it probably doesn't hurt to disclose enough to build or retain that trust.

Comment: I brought it up because these policies often specify exactly which relatives are defined as family and many if not most employers do not consider domestic partners and their family emergencies as family. The more socially conservative the physical location of the corporate headquarters and the more socially conservative the senior managers are, the less likely they will think a domestic partner is family.  I agree that most of the time, it is easier to get this leave if you tell your boss what is going on.

Answer (score 8):

1. Check your companie's policy. That should be covered there.
2. If that's unclear or you are out of days, check with HR
3. In the US it's mostly "PTO" these days, i.e. you have a single blob of time for vacation, illness and/or addressing personal issues. This is one of the latter and so you should be covered. You still get paid
4. If you need more time, you can try a personal leave of absences. It's unpaid. However that's tricky to do on the fast.
5. Once you understand the policy and options, figure out what specifically you want to do (3 days off, work remotely for a while, etc). Then talk to your boss. Discuss options, tying up lose ends, how to stay in touch, impact on current projects, etc.
6. Check with your partner and parents if the trip is really necessary. While this is a tough situation, it's less clear what your partner actually needs to accomplish. It could be that the parents are in a fight and want her take side. That's useless and stressful and doesn't help anyone. Consider saying something like "I'm really sorry that you have differences you can't work out. I love you both equally but I don't think I can help you work through a separation. Instead I really need to focus and making sure that your future grandchild will be healthy and off to a good start. I hope you understand that this is our highest priority right now"

Comment: #6 is a valid point, but it would be a tricky issue to raise if the partner feels she needs to go.

Comment: Per #6, I would be very surprised if her doctor wanted her to go.